# Get posts from event wall?

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, posts

Is there any way, with the current tools, to fetch the posts from the event wall?

Is there any way to use FQL, REST or anything else to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using the [`event` object in the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<event_id>/feed
```

You'll need a valid access token and the `user_events` or the `friends_events` permissions as well.

Comment: It sucks... this should be in FQL also, and be available without the permissions, because they are public :/

Comment: This doesn't work: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=438921426145061%2Ffeed

Comment: If you authenticated the Graph API Explorer app without the user_events permission, remove that app from your privacy settings, then re-authenticate. Doesn't make sense to me that that permission is necessary, but it is.